# Async GUI using WebForms and .NET 4.5 await/async

Tags: asp.net, webforms, async-await

I've been looking for any simple example building async interfaces using ASP.NET WebForms. That is when an `async` method is done the `await` shall render.

This is one of the examples I've been looking at, [How and When to use `async` and `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/async-and-await). The implementation I've been looking for would look something like this

```
protected async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Render when done
    textBox1.Text += await WaitAsynchronouslyAsync(RandomNumber(2000, 4000));

    // Render when done
    textBox1.Text += await WaitAsynchronouslyAsync(RandomNumber(100, 1000));
}

public async Task<string> WaitAsynchronouslyAsync(int delay)
{
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    return string.Concat(delay, "; ");
}
private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

This will however always render when everything is done, but at the same time. In the example above the desired result would be the second call to `WaitAsynchronouslyAsync` to render before the first call since it always will be less delay.

Or is it even possible using webforms? I do know how to do this in JavaScript using webapi's, websockets and whatnot and that's **not** the solution I desire at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I describe on my blog, [`async` does not change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html).

HTTP provides you with one response for each request. So, when an HTTP request arrives, it must execute your page *to completion* before sending the response.

In the ASP.NET world, `await` does *not* yield to the client/browser. Instead, it yields to the ASP.NET runtime. ASP.NET will not send the response until it sees that your processing is all done.

If you want to dynamically update a page (or partially render one), then you'll need to do it yourself using an appropriate technology (SignalR, UpdatePanel, etc).

Comment: Ah, figures. I was hoping there were some library I could use that simplifies the handling of this. But since the methods and their implementation is async (and will run to the bitter end) all I need is a state changing mechanism that will update the page whenever the status of the methods have changed I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `await` in the manner that you did, execution flow is sequential. The first `await`, and only after it finishes will the second `await` execute.

If you want them executed *concurrently*, you can initiate both operations and use `Task.WhenAny` and assign the value of whichever task finishes first:

```
Task<string> slowerTask = WaitAsynchronouslyAsync(RandomNumber(2000, 4000));
Task<string> fasterTask = WaitAsynchronouslyAsync(RandomNumber(100, 1000));

List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>> { slowerTask, fasterTask };

while (tasks.Count > 0)
{
     Task<string> finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
     tasks.Remove(finishedTask);

     textBox1.Text = await finishedTask;
}
```

Comment: @EricHerlitz Sorry about that, was on the mobile. Edited my code.

Comment: It works in one way, next step is to figure out if there is any way to have the web controls async

Comment: The methods are still running event if I close the page, but the page wont update the textbox async

Comment: Im not really sure what you mean.